# how to save dropdown list value to database in django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, dropdown

I am doing an attendance system and the student is able to mark their attendance by looking for their name in the dropdown list value. The student will then press submit and the information will be stored in MarkAtt database. Currently it did not display the students name accordingly to class, and when i click submit it display the following errors: "valueerror" showed up. ValueError Exception Value: Cannot assign ", , ......"MarkAtt.studName" must be a "Namelist" instance. I need the selected name of the students to be stored in the database per one click....

```
 class MarkAtt(models.Model):
studName = models.ForeignKey(Namelist,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
currentDate = models.DateField(default=now())
week = models.IntegerField(default=0)
attendance = models.IntegerField(default=1) #1 is present
```

The Template displays the class information, today's date and the student's name in a drop drown list box.

```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
Lab Group: {{group.classGrp}} //this is from another view
Day: {{group.day}} 
Time: {{group.time}} 
 Today's date: {{today.date}}
    {{form.as_p}}
```

The view:

```
  def mark_stud(request,id):
group = GroupInfo.objects.get(id=id)
studName = Namelist.objects.filter(classGrp=id)
information = {}
information['group'] = group
information['studName'] =studName
if request.method == 'POST':        
    form = studentAttendanceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        att = form.save(commit=False)
        att.studName = information['studName']
        att.currentDate = datetime.datetime.now.date()
        form.save()
        return redirect('namelist.html')
else: 
    form = studentAttendanceForm()



return render(request, 'namelist.html', {'information' :information, 'form':form})
```

Forms.py

class studentAttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MarkAtt 
        fields = ['studName']
        label = {
        'name': 'Student Name'
        }

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(studentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['studName'].label = "Select your name:"
```

However, the form did not display in the template page and i am unable to save the value in the database. Really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Share your forms.py file

Comment: Sorry, edited my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to separate `GET` and `POST` request in your view, for example:

```
if request.method == POST:
    form = studentAttendanceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        att = form.save(commit=False)
        att.studName = information['studName']
        att.currentDate = datetime.datetime.now.date()
        form.save()
        return redirect('namelist.html')
else: # for GET request
    form = studentAttendanceForm()

return render(request, 'namelist.html', {'information' :information, 'form':form})
```

for your form, it would be better to use `fields` instead of `exclude`:

```
class studentAttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MarkAtt 
        fields = ('studName')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(studentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['studName'].label = "Select your name:"
```

then in your template,
if you use `form.as_p`, you don't have to call `form.att.label_tag`, and don't have to place it inside `<p>` tag
see docs: [form.as_p](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#as-p)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
...
{{form.as_p}}
...
```

ok another problem is, what is `group` and `today` in your template?

```
Lab Group: {{group.classGrp}} 
Day: {{group.day}} 
Time: {{group.time}} 
Today's date: {{today.date}}
```

you didn't include `group` and `today` in your view, so it should be print nothing.
because in your render function, you only send `information` and `form`,
there's no `group` and `today`
`return render(request, 'namelist.html', {'information' :information, 'form':form})`
to increase readability code, it would be better to write like this:

```
context = {
    'information': information,
    'form': form,
    'group': ......, # fill this
    'today': ...... # fill this too
}
return render(request, 'namelist.html', context)
```

---

EDITED

to specify the dropdown list based on the group id, you can pass the group object and use `.queryset` in `__init__` form

```
group = GroupInfo.objects.get(id=id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = studentAttendanceForm(request.POST, class_group=group)
    ...
else:
    form = studentAttendanceForm(request.POST, class_group=group)
```

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    class_group = kwargs.pop('class_group')
    super(studentAttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['studName'].label = "Select your name:" 
    self.fields['studName'].queryset = Namelist.objects.filter(classGrp=class_group)
```

Comment: tried to change. but the form still does not display in my template page...

Comment: ok so there's several problems in your code, I've edited my answer

Comment: tried again but to no avail.. not sure why it is not displaying the dropdown list. Isit there anything i need to specify to let them know i want it to be in drop down list?

Comment: have you tried `{{ form.studName }}` instead of `{{ form.as_p }}` ?

Comment: It is successfully displayed because i did not call the view. When i click submit, an errorr, "valueerror" showed up. ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Namelist: ABHISHEK SINGH>, <Namelist: AGGARWAL ANOUSHKA>, <Namelist: ARVIND KANNAYA SOMU>, <Namelist: : and etc. How do i submit the selected name to database

Comment: can you update your post with your current code so i can try check the problem?

Comment: Hi lieahau! edited my code with the current problem. Personally, i feel the error is trying to add all the students at once. But thts not what i want. I think i am missing something like "selected_name" or etc.

Comment: hi, probably it is because this code `att.studName = information['studName']`.. why? `att` is your saved form which means it already have the value of `studName` from your template on form submit. then you trying to assign new value with `information['studName']` which is a queryset of Namelist. so try remove that line of code and see what happen

Comment: Ive removed the code and i have problem making the the website stays at the same page. When i click submit, it shows me an error page, saying the page does not found. But when i check my database, it saved! good news! however, there are still prob... Do u think u can help me still?

Comment: how do i specify like the dropdown list should display the names based on the group id? Like groupid = 1: the dropdown list shld display: puteri, adam, princess. grpid=2: display: tom,mary ? Right now when i click different grp id, it shows the same name for all id. not sure how to specify it since i am using django form

Comment: page not found because you use `redirect` for .html, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), you have to write your `view` name instead of the .html file

Comment: Thank you so much lieahau for helping me till this stage! now, it managed to display the correct names and saved in my database!! thank you so much. as for the redirect: i actually changed it to "mark:listname" -> my view name but how do i pass again the current group id that was being passed previously?

Comment: its okay! ive managed to figure it out by myself. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

I think your form won't show up because it is only defined inside the "try and except" part. Try having your code like this:

```
def mark_stud(request, class_id,id):
    form = studentAttendanceForm(request.POST)
    if (not class_id or not id):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    else:
        try:
            classGrp = None
            information = {}
            information['studName'] = Namelist.objects.get(name=id)


            if form.is_valid():
                att = form.save(commit=False)
                att.studName = information['studName']
                att.currentDate = datetime.datetime.now.date()
                form.save()
                return redirect('namelist.html')

        except ObjectsDoesNotExist:
            print("no entries")
            return redirect('namelist.html')        

    return render(request, 'namelist.html', {'information' :information, 'form':form})
```